# Windows store legacy app (metro) experiencing random file access errors on Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-store-apps, windbg, rpc

I have an old metro app which needs to run on Windows 10. It performs file operations on Documents Library for interop with other processes running on the same machine.

Line causing the issue:

```
StorageFolder flagFolder = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFolderAsync(dirPath);
```

Most of the times, it runs fine, but every now and then it runs into a strange issue, which I cannot find a solution for:

```
  Message: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
  Source : Windows.Storage
  Type   : System.Exception
  Stack  :
   at Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.get_DocumentsLibrary()
   at XXX.<TimerTick>d__a.MoveNext()
```

At the same time, this app reported as crashed in Event Viewer - even though it actually continued to run.

The exception above got recorded many times in my log file, however the crash below got reported only once. It can't be coincidental though, the Event Viewer logged crash happened at the exact same time when the app started throwing exceptions above.

```
Faulting application name: RuntimeBroker.exe, version: 10.0.19041.746, time stamp: 0x5b78739c
Faulting module name: shcore.dll, version: 10.0.19041.746, time stamp: 0x5e98fab6
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000022227
Faulting process id: 0xe94
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8f4397cb4625c
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\RuntimeBroker.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\shcore.dll
Report Id: ce450896-5110-4b5e-9aa2-a6ea4182d40a
Faulting package full name: XXX
Faulting package-relative application ID: runtimebroker07f4358a809ac99a64a67c1
```

As far as I can tell, some of the app functionalities were not working properly anymore:

1. It seems like it does not allow to register any more threads from threadpool from this moment on.
2. Timers relying on threadpool stopped functioning as well.
3. Interestingly, it still keeps logging to a log file, which was opened earlier.
4. Sometime later (like, half an hour), the app lost ability to open and write another file in Documents Library - it also crashed with the same exception as above.

I used windbg on the dump file, here's the stack:

```
[0x0]   ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects + 0x14   
[0x1]   KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx + 0xf0   
[0x2]   KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjects + 0xe   
[0x3]   kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal + 0x58a   
[0x4]   kernel32!WerpReportFault + 0xbe   
[0x5]   KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter + 0x3d9   
[0x6]   ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart$filt$0 + 0xa2   
[0x7]   ntdll!_C_specific_handler + 0x96   
[0x8]   ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException + 0xf   
[0x9]   ntdll!RtlDispatchException + 0x244   
[0xa]   ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch + 0x2e   
[0xb]   SHCore!COplockFileHandle::_Initialize + 0x167   
[0xc]   SHCore!COplockFileHandle::s_CreateInstance + 0xaa   
[0xd]   SHCore!SHManagedCreateFile + 0x1ff   
[0xe]   SHCore!CSafeSaveHandleManager::_EnsureMainHandle + 0x154   
[0xf]   SHCore!CSafeSaveHandleManager::GetHandleForRead + 0x4a   
[0x10]   SHCore!`anonymous namespace'::_CreateRandomAccessStreamOnFileHelper + 0xd6   
[0x11]   SHCore!CreateRandomAccessStreamOnFileWithOptions + 0x19   
[0x12]   windows_storage!CFSFolder::_BindToChild + 0xdb3   
[0x13]   windows_storage!CFSFolder::_Bind + 0x9de   
[0x14]   windows_storage!CFSFolder::BindToObject + 0x44e   
[0x15]   windows_storage!CShellItem::BindToHandler + 0x548   
[0x16]   windows_storage!_CreateRandomAccessStream + 0xeb   
[0x17]   windows_storage!CShellItem::BindToHandler + 0x67b   
[0x18]   windows_storage!CStorageFileBase::s_OpenAsyncPrivateWorker + 0x1ae   
[0x19]   windows_storage!<lambda_6590a290d3704fa33cc8569c7c432ebe>::operator() + 0x135   
[0x1a]   windows_storage!<lambda_b0a6a9cfa44b8f830e3e8e8eecceff13>::operator() + 0x74   
[0x1b]   windows_storage!Windows::Internal::COperationLambdaVar<0,<lambda_b0a6a9cfa44b8f830e3e8e8eecceff13>,Windows::Internal::CMarshaledInterfaceResult<Windows::Storage::Streams::IInputStream> >::Run + 0x23   
[0x1c]   windows_storage!Windows::Internal::AsyncOperation<Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<Windows::Storage::Streams::IInputStream *>,Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperationCompletedHandler<Windows::Storage::Streams::IInputStream *>,Windows::Internal::CMarshaledInterfaceResult<Windows::Storage::Streams::IInputStream>,Windows::Internal::ComTaskPoolHandler,Windows::Internal::INilDelegate,Microsoft::WRL::AsyncOptions<-1,0,&GUID_CAUSALITY_WINDOWS_PLATFORM_ID,2> >::Run + 0x79   
[0x1d]   SHCore!WorkThreadManager::CThread::ThreadProc + 0x1d0   
[0x1e]   SHCore!WorkThreadManager::CThread::s_ExecuteThreadProc + 0x18   
[0x1f]   SHCore!<lambda_9844335fc14345151eefcc3593dd6895>::<lambda_invoker_cdecl> + 0x11   
[0x20]   kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x14   
[0x21]   ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart + 0x21
```

```
STACK_COMMAND:  ~4s; .ecxr ; kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  SHCore!COplockFileHandle::_Initialize+167

MODULE_NAME: SHCore

IMAGE_NAME:  SHCore.dll

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_POINTER_READ_c0000005_SHCore.dll!COplockFileHandle::_Initialize

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.19041.746

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {6e7c4134-ffb6-90fc-7715-5adc39084c1a}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

Rebooting the computer fixes the issue, but of course that's not a viable solution for me.
Restarting the app is not enough to fix the issue reliably.

**This app used to run on Windows 8, 8.1 and older versions of Windows 10 and this issue never appeared there.**

Does anybody have any idea what might be going on here?
Has anyone encountered anything similar to the described issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have `KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter` on the call stack. This means the thread encountered an exception but didn't quite crash.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-unhandledexceptionfilter.

Look at the `_EXCEPTION_POINTERS` parameter, it contains an exception record and context record that you can use to set the exception context and context record in the debugger.

This will then allow you to see the frame which caused the exception.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you, will definitely try that! Hopefully your suggestion will help to shed some light on this case.